# Clipping a raster using an irregular polygon with Python

Tags: raster, pyqgis, clip, qgis-processing

I want to clip a raster (GeoTIFF) using a polygon shapefile. Both are in the same reference system. The polygon is not a regular polygon but has many vertices.

I used this Python script below in QGIS 2.18.4

```
    import processing
    processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", \
    "/home/giacomo/Desktop/RSM/bordi.tif", \
    "/home/giacomo/Desktop/RSM/mask_vec.shp", \
    "none", \
    False, \
    True, \
    True, \
    "", \
    "", \
    0, \
    0, \
    0, \
    False, \
    "", \
    False, \
    "", \
    "/home/giacomo/Desktop/RSM/bordi_clip.tif")
```

But I get Error: Wrong parameter value:

The parameters required as input are

```
    INPUT <ParameterRaster>
    MASK <ParameterVector>
    NO_DATA <ParameterString>
    ALPHA_BAND <ParameterBoolean>
    CROP_TO_CUTLINE <ParameterBoolean>
    KEEP_RESOLUTION <ParameterBoolean>
    RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
    COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
    JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
    ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
    PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
    TILED <ParameterBoolean>
    BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
    TFW <ParameterBoolean>
    EXTRA <ParameterString>
    OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

Firstly, you need to specify your input layers as objects (and not as strings):

```
raster_filepath = "C:/Users/path_to_the_raster/bordi.tif"
mask_filepath = "C:/Users/path_to_the_shapefile/mask_vec.shp"

raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(raster_filepath, 'raster')
mask_layer = QgsVectorLayer(mask_filepath, 'mask', 'ogr')
```

Then, you didn't specify the `RTYPE` parameter:

```
RTYPE(Output raster type)
    0 - Byte
    1 - Int16
    2 - UInt16
    3 - UInt32
    4 - Int32
    5 - Float32
    6 - Float64
```

You can't set `""` as value (as you did), but a number is required.

The same with the `COMPRESS` parameter:

```
COMPRESS(GeoTIFF options. Compression type:)
    0 - NONE
    1 - JPEG
    2 - LZW
    3 - PACKBITS
    4 - DEFLATE
```

You can't set `""` as value (as you did), but a number is required.

Therefore, you set `0` as value for `JPEGCOMPRESSION`, `ZLEVEL` and `PREDICTOR` parameters. They can't be equal to *0* so, if you don't know what they mean, leave the default values (i.e. `75`, `6` and `1`, respectively).

Then, you didn't specify the `BIGTIFF` parameter:

```
BIGTIFF(Control whether the created file is a BigTIFF or a classic TIFF)
    0 - 
    1 - YES
    2 - NO
    3 - IF_NEEDED
    4 - IF_SAFER
```

Finally, you can't set `""` as value, but a number is required.

A working solution for you should be this:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

raster_filepath = "C:/Users/path_to_the_raster/bordi.tif"
mask_filepath = "C:/Users/path_to_the_shapefile/mask_vec.shp"

raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(raster_filepath, 'raster')
mask_layer = QgsVectorLayer(mask_filepath, 'mask', 'ogr')

processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", \
raster_layer, \
mask_layer, \
"none", \
False, \
True, \
True, \
5, \
4, \
75, \
6, \
1, \
False, \
0, \
False, \
"", \
"C:/Users/path_to_the_result/output.tif")
```

Comment: I was using the QgsRasterLayer in the wrong way. Mgri's solution works. Thank you

Comment: @ilFonta You're welcome. I'm glad you found it helpful! =)

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an updated solution for QGIS 3 as some things have changed. I referenced various other StackOverflow threads and the [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) page to make it work.

First, I'd like to mention this command that was hugely helpful to me. From the console you can run:

```
processing.algorithmHelp('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer')
```

This prints out step-by-step instructions for the parameters, what values are accepted, etc. I used this to populate my parameter values.

Here is a code example:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer('path to your input raster', 'raster')
mask_layer = QgsVectorLayer('path to your vector mask layer', 'mask', 'ogr')

parameters = {'INPUT': raster_layer,
            'MASK': mask_layer,
            'NODATA': -9999,
            'ALPHA_BAND': False,
            'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
            'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
            'OPTIONS': None,
            'DATA_TYPE': 0,
            'OUTPUT': 'path to where you want to save'}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer', parameters)
```

A nice way to build your parameters list is to make a dictionary with them before feeding them into the GDAL tool.

Also, notice the processing.runandload method from QGIS 2 has now become processing.runAndLoadResults in QGIS 3.

Comment: Thank you Erich, I think it's time to move QGIS3 as well

Answer (score 2):

If you use backslash (\) in your code it won't work. On the other hand, you need to put as "False" both 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' and 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' if you want to preserve alignment with original raster. In my case, with these layers loaded at Map View of QGIS:

[image]

next code:

```
import processing

mask = processing.getObjectFromName('polygon2')
input = processing.getObjectFromName('utah_demUTM2')

path = processing.runandload('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', 
                             input,    #INPUT <ParameterRaster>
                             mask,     #MASK <ParameterVector>
                             "-9999",  #NO_DATA <ParameterString>
                             False,    #ALPHA_BAND <ParameterBoolean>
                             False,    #CROP_TO_CUTLINE <ParameterBoolean>
                             False,    #KEEP_RESOLUTION <ParameterBoolean>
                             5,        #RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
                             4,        #COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
                             1,        #JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
                             6,        #ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
                             1,        #PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
                             False,    #TILED <ParameterBoolean>
                             0,        #BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
                             False,    #TFW <ParameterBoolean>
                             "",       #EXTRA <ParameterString>
                             None)     #OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

produces a mask perfectly aligned with base raster; as you can corroborate with Value Tool plugin of QGIS (see next image):

[image]

'None' option as output raster produces a temporary layer loaded from **/tmp** directory. To preserve this resulting layer it's necessary to save it (or you can use your initial path: "/home/giacomo/Desktop/RSM/bordi_clip.tif").

Comment: Hi, I tried several combination of parameters, but always get Error: Wrong parameter value: None. `import processing

mask = processing.getObjectFromName('mask_vec.shp')
input = processing.getObjectFromName('bordi.tif')

path = processing.runandload('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', input, mask, None, False, False, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, False, "", None)`

Comment: @ilFonta you are setting `0` values when it's not possible doing it. Please, see the explanation in my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @ilFonta Load your raster and your mask in QGIS. Copy/paste my code as another script. Change 'polygon2' and 'utah_demUTM2' for your respective names. Run it. It should work.