# Wrong parameter value error when passing a raster to clip in iteration loop in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, clip, qgis-processing

The overall aim of this is to clip a raster (rlayer), feature by feature of a shapefile (vlayer). Then run univariate stats on each clipped DEM. Passing the answer to a table for output.

However I have fallen at the first hurdle and cannot get clip to work. Example error:

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: <qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x000000002455D9D8>
```

My code as of the moment is:

```
#Load the required modules
from qgis.core import*
import qgis.utils
import processing
import os

#Load administrative polygons
vlayer = (iface.addVectorLayer
("C:/Users/geol-tdi/Documents/UK_NUTS.shp",
"nutspoly",
"ogr"))
if not vlayer:
    print "Vector layer failed to load!"

#Load raster for analysis
rlayer = (iface.addRasterLayer
("C:/Users/geol-tdi/Documents/Rasters/UKwheatPEC80div50.tif", 
"WheatD"))
if not rlayer:
    print "Raster layer failed to load!"

#Iteratively analyse admin polys. 
vlayer.selectAll()
features = vlayer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
    vlayer.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
    print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()
    processing.runalg('qgis:clip',rlayer, feature, None )  
    vlayer.removeSelection()

vlayer.removeSelection()
```

I have tried variations such as naming the selected feature before passing it to the algorithm but that fails as well. Output is currently set to NONE to allow testing/pass the result to the univaraite stats alg when I get there.

I am aware this is likely a simple problem/mistake, but I am relatively new to this.

Note that I have already tried v.rast.stats from the processing toolbox, it fails to write any output to the shapefile, for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input layer and clip layer for that processing tool only clips vector data, not raster data.  You are trying to clip a raster layer.

> Input layer [vector: any]  Clip layer
>   [vector: any]

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html

To clip a raster by vector see:

[Clipping a raster using an irregular polygon with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233279/clipping-a-raster-using-an-irregular-polygon-with-python)

[How to clip a raster by a shapefile in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90982/how-to-clip-a-raster-by-a-shapefile-in-pyqgis)

Comment: I knew it was something silly... many thanks indeed for your time and excellent links.

Comment: However, I am still failing to pass the selected polygon to the now correct clip algorithm sorry.

Comment: To close this question, I changed plan as still could not get clip to accept the passed/selected polygon. Therefore have split the polygons and am running stats from there.